# Verses number in upanishads

Tags: upanishads

I want a list of upanishads in a specific order. The order should be smallest to biggest that is upanishads with least verses to upanishads with most verses.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is your question limited to 11 Principal Upanishads?

Comment: No, I want list of every Upanishads. I want to know which Upanishads has less numbers of verses & which has more. This will help me to complete those Upanishads first which have lesser number of verses, then I will move to longer ones.

Answer (score 1):

Upanishad   Number of verses

Māṇḍūkya Upanishad  12

Ishavasya Upanishad 18

Taittirīya Upanishad    30

Aitareya Upanishad  33

Kena Upanishad  35

Kaushitaki Upanishad    50

Mundaka Upanishad   65

Praṣna Upanishad    67

Maitri Upanishad    73

Shvetashvatara Upanishad    113

Kaṭha Upanishad 119

Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upanishad 434

Chāndogya Upanishad 627

there might be slight variations in the number of verses from different sources.

Comment: I want this kind of list not just for 13 main Upanishads but for every Upanishads. Each & every one.